# How to create an input with datalist dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, datalist

I'm trying to create dynamycally some datalists. My problem happen when I try to embed it in an input.
I tried this code but `newinput.list="DL"` doesn't work. ()

```
var newinput = document.createElement("input");
    newinput.className="nom";
    newinput.id= file_header[i];
    newinput.type= "text";
    newinput.list="DL";

document.getElementById("head_menu").appendChild(newdiv);
```

Input is created but without `list` attributes...
Can someone explain me how to link my input with my datalist?

Comment: I'm unable to offer an answer, but does `newinput.setAttribute('list', 'DL');` work?

Comment: thanks for trying....and it works!

Comment: Add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try what @David is saying .. it worked for me.

newinput.setAttribute('list', 'DL');

Comment: It worked for me too, as written in comments, but so far it's just a comment and not an answer, I can't solve the question